# Limiting Self-Answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers

After marveling at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143806/mysql-performance-issue), it occurred to me that there should be a limit on self-answers on non-wiki questions. This is mainly to protect the user from themselves so they can only use comments to respond, not inadvertantly spam the answer list.

Obviously, the user is not a native English speaker, so s/he may not get the subtle difference between a comment and an answer. If coming from the forum world, that shiny text box at the bottom of the post is the only way to respond.

**Edit:** Following Kyle's comment: How about a way for a mod to turn an answer into a comment?

Comment: Maybe a mod function to turn an answer into a comment?

Comment: @Kyle Cronin : I didn't see your comment and answered the question. Agreed !

Comment: The promote/demote question has been asked http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6074/answer-new-question

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36247/rep-requirement-for-answering-own-question

Comment: @Kyle: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35175/should-moderators-be-able-to-convert-answers-into-comments

Answer (score 10):

The "Your Answer" box isn't shown on your own questions. It's replaced by an "Answer Your Question" button and you get the following dialog if you click it:

> Are you sure you want to answer your own question?
>
> If you're responding to answers left on your question, enter comments under each answer.
>
> If you need to add details to your own question, use the edit link under your question.

If you persist after that, well....

Comment: Fair enough, but I think a hard limit (on non-wikis) would be a good idea. Also, the guy is obviously panicked and has no idea how to have an English conversation, and so is clicking through whatever boxes you throw at him.

Comment: Warning dialogs are so overused, particularly in Windows software, that few people read them anymore.  Almost everybody gets trained to click what they need to do to get the [obscenity] box away and get back to what they were doing.  I suspect people with limited English skills are going to be more prone to it.

Answer (score 8):

We already do this, for ALL users on questions they own.

[image]

Note:

1. **The standard answer editor does NOT appear by default for post owners**. Instead there is a single "Answer Your Question" button.
2. Clicking the "Answer Your Question" button nags you:

   > Are you sure you want to answer your own question?
   >
   > If you're responding to answers left on your question, enter
   >   comments under each answer.
   >
   > If you need to add details to your own question, use the edit
   >   link under your question.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, except as we all know - [users don't read][1]. What this and other related questions are getting at is that its still too easy to do the wrong thing.

  [1]: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001306.html

Comment: cure worse than disease, though.

Comment: This particular solution to the problem may or may not be, but I wonder if there isn't a better solution as what we are doing clearly isn't as effective as could be desired. And/or at least having the ability to move the "comment" to the appropriate place may help be as instructive.

Comment: @Arjan ugh, indeed.. fixing.

Answer (score 6):

That specific example is obvious spamming of the board.  Just flag it.  A moderator will handle it and the user will either learn how to behave or move on.

For other less obvious posts, there's already a warning that comes up when you answer your own question.

Comment: Agreed.  One example does not make a pandemic.