# Anti-gaming algorithm details

Tags: discussion, down-votes, gaming-the-system

Regarding [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143806/mysql-performance-issue) that [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6593/limiting-self-answers) covers, if I were to go into that thread and downvote every answer sm1 made in response to his own question, would the nightly anti-gaming algorithm undo the downvotes?

If so, do you think it's correct for it to undo the downvotes?

(n.b. It's not that I downvoted all his answers, but I was very tempted to do it. So I wondered what would happen if I did.)

Comment: **Fact:** The only gaming the system cannot stop is the Taxonomist badge.

Comment: Oooh... I was gonna chide you for being a cruel heartless bastard, punishing newbies like that... Then i saw he used "urgent" in *three different "answers"* ... i'll help.

Comment: Some affable mod has dealt with those answers now, but man oh man, that was one of the more impressive questions I've seen. Shog's description doesn't really even do it justice. Also, what is it about some non-native speakers that they think "urgent" is going to get help faster? I think the only thing I ever use the word "urgent" for is when we have to make it to the next rest area ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mutual acquaintance and fellow SO user has told me that the system catches anything beyond two downvotes to a user in a given day.  I don't know how he arrived at this information, but he's the sort who would have tested it to determine the limit.

Comment: You're sure it applies even if all the votes originate from the same thread?

Comment: I'm not sure of anything, except that this fellow has probably poked and prodded the system like those raptors did to the electrified fence in *Jurassic Park*.

Comment: You get accepted, but only because you're so delicious on pasta. Also because I don't know what an *RSolberg* tastes like. Whatever it is, it sounds nasty.

Comment: Probably not very good...  I would have accepted this one too if it were my question...

Answer (score 1):

I personally think every post (including this one) is made with the risk that it could get downvoted.  That is just part of the system.  If you don't want to get rep damage, you should make the question CW.  I would hope that the system doesn't go back through and potentially remove those...

Comment: -1 because that's not the purpose of CW.