# Newish users answering own questions with what should be question edits

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, new-users, site-usage

I'm seeing more users who ask their question, and engage in discussion in comments (under their question, and under my own answers), but then the conversation gets to a point where what *I* think is needed is for them to edit their question with a clarification.

Then what they do is add a new answer to their own question with the clarification. This is frustrating because then it's a matter of telling them "hey, what you really want to do is update your question."

Now, on your own question, there is an `alert()` that pops up that says:

> **Are you sure you want to answer your
>   own question?**
>
> **If you're responding to answers left
>   under your question, use the comments
>   link under each answer.**

My suggestion is that this could be updated to say something like:

> If you need to add details 
>   to your original
>   question, use "edit" to add examples, details, code you've tried, etc.

There may be another way to handle it, but some newer users seem not to get it, and I suspect a UI change might help alleviate this practice.

Comment: Even more, the sites show [the comment fields expanded by default for new users on answers to questions they own](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36247/rep-requirement-for-answering-own-question#comment-79008). But indeed, some still don't get it...

Comment: Good point. There are times when self-answering is fine, but a little discouragement to self-answer, and a little encouragement to edit their question would be good. I think a small change could make a good impact. Even a little text next to the [Answer Your Question] button like "answer your question is meant for solutions - if you need to change or add details to your question, use edit, not Answer Your Question" ... obviously needs a writer. :-)

Comment: @arlung: *Are you sure you want to answer your own question? If you're responding to answers left on your question, use the comments link under each answer.* appears when trying to self answer.

Comment: @perbert That's right! I think we encourage users to use comments great! What we don't tell people is that they should **EDIT** their question if they need to add details or add clarifications. Instead, I see users adding an answer when what they mean to do is refine their question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok, changed to

> Are you sure you want to answer your own question?
>
> If you're responding to answers left on your question, enter comments under each answer.
>
> If you need to add details to your question, use the edit link under your question.

Comment: Great! I hope it has an impact!