# Dealing with questions posted as answers that have actually been answered

Tags: discussion, flags, review

While reviewing I occasionally stumble upon "answers" like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2329643/507519) or [this pair](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4761986/507519) [of posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4971707/507519). Both cases consist of a question that has been posted as an answer and then has been subsequently answered, although in the second case the thread was practically hijacked by a single user...

Most often, the question is related to another answer and everything can be demoted to a bunch of comments. In some cases, though, this would not really make sense. I normally flag these as "Not an answer", but in some cases I have felt that the content was worth preserving in some form.

- It seems to me that the answer in the first case took some effort. Is there a way to preserve it, while maintaining the proper Q&A format?

  Alternatively, would it make sense for a reviewer to let posts like this be, in order to preserve the content? I have routinely let some far more useless posts be, simply because they actually *were* answers, even if it was barely so.

  Is there a fine line somewhere, or should reviewers follow a strict "No questions as answers" and flag away, even for years-old threads?
- In cases like the second one, should I flag both the question-as-answer and the answering post? The answering post would probably not make much sense after the question has been deleted...

Comment: Related: [Convert non-answers into new questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6074/convert-non-answers-into-new-questions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ... or should reviewers follow a strict "No questions as answers" and flag away, even for years-old threads?

Yes. [Fortunately, and especially, since it has already been re-asked as a question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329630/nhibernate-and-oracle-lite) Moderators can't move an answer from one question to another, however, so I have left a comment on the question-as-answer asking Thomas if he'd like to do it so I can remove the bad post.

> In cases like the second one, should I flag both the question-as-answer and the answering post?

If the answering post answers the question-as-answer, and *not the original question*, then flag that along with the question-as-answer.

Comment: I've flagged posts like this before and found out that moderators don't have that power -- does it come up often enough that you _would_ like that power? I've only seen three or four cases myself.

Comment: @sarnold: Same here. Personally, I think it'd be nice. I'll have to be really careful with it, though ;)

Comment: And there's a point of how much janitorial work are we alright putting on our small team of mods -- at some point, a big negative "close" hammer sends a lesson that might not be learned if you guys magically make things right all the time...

Comment: Indeed. As in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation), most mod interventions are meant to be exceptional.