# Comments on late-answer review

Tags: discussion, comments, review

I was reviewing [this late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/1742276), which is actually a question, so I flagged it for moderator attention. Then, I missed the feature of leaving a comment (which is available in the queue of low quality posts) for telling the user that he/she should have posted it as a question.

I searched the review in my history, opened the answer and wrote a comment... but some doubts remains:

- Are moderators able to convert the answer in a question? (I see that [the user has no questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2182821/user2182821?tab=questions), then I understand that the answer was only deleted).
- Was the user notified (by any means other than my comment) that he should have posted a question instead of asking an answer?
- Might that process be automatized in some way? (This is not a feature request, since I'm not sure that the feature is actually missing).

tl;dr... I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are moderators able to convert the answer in a question? (I see that the user has no questions, then I understand that the answer was only deleted).

No, moderators can convert answers to comments but there is no mechanism in place to convert answers to questions. The [request to convert answers to questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6074/convert-non-answers-into-new-questions) has been asked before but it was declined as a feature request.

> Was the user notified (by any means other than my comment) that he should have posted a question instead of asking an answer?

The user would have gotten the notification of your comment only. There is no other notification that is sent to them that the answer was deleted.

> Might that process be automatized in some way? (This is not a feature request, since I'm not sure that the feature is actually missing).

I am not exactly sure what needs to be automated here. The user gets notification via the comment that you posted.  It is not up to the mods to create a new question based on the answer because it is not as straight forward as converting it to a comment.

The mod would have to create a question title, most likely they would have to clean up the answer to make it a viable question which would take the mods away from their other focus.